# Add shared button on multiple views

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, appdelegate

I'm working on an app that plays some "background" music inside the app. The app contains a number of views but does not use a NavigationController.

I need to add a "mute" button to quite a few views/viewcontrollers that allows the user to mute/unmute the background music. What would be the best way to add this functionality in a single location while allowing me to use it in many different views/viewcontrollers without having to write the same mute/unmute code many times?

Comment: You can also add multiple buttons but call a unique function (in a singleton for example).

Comment: The button needs to change it's appearance depending on whether the sound is muted or unmuted, so I would have to handle that on every single view, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two ideas:

1. You could sub-class UIButton, so you could take care of the appearance in the init function. It could also have a delegate which you can call to mute/unmute.
2. You could have a Class with one public Class function, that takes in a UIButton. It will then style it and add a call to a private Class function via `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. That way, your public function takes care of the style, and the private function takes care of the muting/unmuting.

To elaborate on the second point, you could write a function similar to this

```
+ (void)setupMuteButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mute.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unmute.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(muteButtonTapped:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
}

+ (void)muteButtonTapped:(UIButton *)button
{
    self.selected = !self.selected;
    if(self.selected){
        //code to mute
    }else{
        //code to unmute
    }
}
```

then add `setupMuteButton:` to the Class' interface and then just import that Class, call the function and pass in your button. Since you want to have a mute button all over the place, just add a different button to any of your views and pass them into the function.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second option - What do you mean by "take in a UIButton"? Could you be a bit more specific in how you would implement the central class and how you would implement the button on all the necessary views where it's needed?

Comment: In the meantime i ended up adding a MuteViewController which contains the button and handles the state and then adding it as a childViewController to each viewController needing the button. I'll try out your approach since it seems a bit simpler and easier to move the buttons around on each individual viewController.

Comment: Well it isn't the nice and clean solution I was searching for but your second option can be made to work while still being fairly DRY compliant, so I'll mark it as the answer.